# Как сделать корректный запрос в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Таблица]

Задача получить названия самолетов которые летали и в Ростов и в Париж
делаю так:

SELECT plane FROM trip
WHERE town_from = 'Rostov' AND town_from = 'London';

ожидаю получить: Boeing (только он летал и туда и туда)

Но в ответ пусто. Что не так?

Comment: У вас ошибка во 2-ом условие

Comment: Ну это прямо вопрос из букваря программирования. 
Во-первых, определитесь летали «в» или «из» (`town_from` это «из»). Во вторых, ни один полёт не может быть одновременно и из Ростова и из Парижа, как написано у вас в запросе.

Comment: AND поменяйте на OR

Comment: @AlexeyTen Только Boeing летают ИЗ Ростова И ИЗ Парижа, исходя из этого как правильно составить запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу следующий способ:

```
SELECT 
    plane
FROM
    trips as t
GROUP BY plane
HAVING
    exists(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            trips
        WHERE
            plane = t.plane
            AND
            town_to = "Rostov"
    )
    AND
    exists(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            trips
        WHERE
            plane = t.plane
            AND
            town_to = "Paris"
    )
```

Comment: Думал это проще, а тут целая сложная конструкция) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть и еще один способ. От прошлого он отличается тем, что вы можете не копировать каждый раз огромную конструкцию `exists` для добавления нового города. Вам достаточно лишь создать [временную таблицу](https://snipp.ru/mysql/create-temporary-table)(кратко - таблица существует до закрытия соединения. После использования можно ее вручную удалить, чтобы не висела до закрытия соединения):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE towns_to(
    id INT primary key not null auto_increment,
    name VARCHAR(23)
);
```

Туда можно поместить все города, в которые должен был слетать самолет:

```
INSERT INTO towns_to
(name)
VALUES
    ("Paris"),
    ("Rostov");
```

Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так(использовал [трюк](https://qna.habr.com/q/15730) для проверки, является ли одно множество подмножеством другого):

```
SELECT 
    plane
FROM
    trips as t
GROUP BY plane
HAVING
    not exists(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            towns_to
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                trips
            WHERE
                plane = t.plane
            ) as _set
        ON
            towns_to.name = _set.town_to
        WHERE
            _set.town_to is NULL
    );
```

Вместо временной таблицы можно использовать [таблицу, созданную в самом запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116975/337682). Но это очень новая фича, она появилась в версии [MySQL 8.0.19(2020.01.13(!!!))](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html). Но если заходите использовать - просто замените `FROM towns_to` на `FROM` + строка с созданием такой таблицы. Сам не пробовал, но должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень развернуто.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * 
       FROM trip 
       WHERE town_from = 'Rostov' OR town_from = 'London';
```

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Оно выберет путешествия, в которых самолет летал в Ростов или в Лондон.