# Как создать таблицу, набор значений которой я знаю, ВНУТРИ ЗАПРОСА?

Tags: mysql, sql, таблицы

Хочу сделать что-то типа этого.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (("1", "hi"), ("2", "hello")) as t
```

Comment: Вроде, простая вещь, но вспомнить, как это делается, не могу.

Comment: https://snipp.ru/mysql/create-temporary-table как альтернатива вашей задаче. Временные таблицы

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо, это решает проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В версии 8.0.19 был добавлен синтаксис [`VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html). То есть для вашего примера коректно будет так:

```
values row("1", "hi"), row("2", "hello")
```

(это полностью запрос). Или как бессмысленный пример но для демонстрации использования в более сложных запросах:

```
select * from (values row("1", "hi"), row("2", "hello")) as t;
```

---

В более старых версиях - только собирать построчно через `union all`. Или в `temporary` табличку предварительно писать и потом работать с ней.

Comment: Эх, у меня 8.0.18)) Почему, в общем-то, спрашиваю. Задача такова - узнать, содержится ли одно множество в другом. Она решается следующим способом: https://qna.habr.com/q/15730. Одно множество я знаю(меньшее множество). Но решение требует того, чтобы оно было таблицей. Поэтому мне нужно внутри запроса представить меньшее множество в виде таблицы. Вы не знаете решения этой задачи на более ранних версиях?

Comment: см. под горизонтальной чертой. Других вариантов нет.